# How to add filtering to the printing and sorting them

Tags: java, sorting, filter

Kind of a misleading title but what i'm trying to do is to change the output so the it'll only print based on those filtering based on the argument. If is empty then it prints it as normal but if its something like platform=PC then it'll only print the platforms in PC

I think the there is too much code so http://pastebin.com/GrtJNfhv this pastebin is my code

The output I want and the desire output are below

Output

```
0:1     Quick Fingers  CastleRock     XB
2:0     Colour Demon  Cirronith     PS
1:0     Quick Fingers  Crayonbreath     PS
2:1     Quick Fingers  Deathstar     IO
1:1     Number Picker  GreenPanda     AN
1:1     Quick Fingers  Ithroeann     IO
0:1     Colour Demon  Mazzzap     AN
0:1     Number Picker  Mazzzap     AN
1:0     Quick Fingers  Mazzzap     AN
1:0     Colour Demon  Quinesia     XB
1:0     Number Picker  Quinesia     XB
1:1     Colour Demon  Redstripe     PC
1:0     Number Picker  Redstripe     PC
1:0     Quick Fingers  Redstripe     PC
1:0     Number Picker  TorpedoBear     PC
0:1     Colour Demon  VolcanoBrawler     PC
0:2     Number Picker  VolcanoBrawler     PC
0:1     Quick Fingers  VolcanoBrawler     PC
```

Desire Output if argument is platform=PC

```
1:1 Colour Demon Redstripe PC
0:2 Number Picker VolcanoBrawler PC
1:0 Number Picker Redstripe PC
1:0 Number Picker TorpedoBear PC
1:0 Quick Fingers Redstripe PC
0:1 Quick Fingers VolcanoBrawler PC
0:1 Colour Demon VolcanoBrawler PC
```

Another question is how do i make the sorted values to a descending order if the argument has "desc" so if the args[0] is platform=PC desc it'll print the desire output but its at a descending order

Comment: Do you have any language requirements? If this is a unix system then grep 'PC' would work perfectly. Or even better, awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "} $5 ~ /PC/{print $0}'

Comment: @David: Pastebin dump points to java

Comment: Remove irrelevant parts of your code and include it in your question.

Comment: Do you have a problem parsing the argument or filtering the list based on a property?

Comment: I have problem filtering the list I don't think parsing will be that much of a problem.

Comment: Do you have to process this output or can you filter based on the Java datastructures?

Comment: Have a look at Stream.filter